Quill moves custom attribute
I'm using Quill (v.2.0.0) with quill-better-table (v.1.2.10) in my Angular 13 project.
I'm trying to add a custom attribute to the table tag, something like
<table class="quill-better-table" custom-attribute="test" style="width: 100px;">

Everything seems ok and the correct string corresponding to the inner html of quill is saved in my database, and also includes my custom attribute in the table tag. However, when I reload the content (reading, therefore), Quill cuts or moves my attribute to the col tag, whatever the Scope I set:
<table class="quill-better-table" style="width: 100px;">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="100" custom-attribute="test">
        </colgroup>
...

There is my Quill configuration:
const Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');
const customAttribute = new Parchment.Attributor('custom-attribute', 'custom-attribute', {
    scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK,
    whitelist: ['test']
});
Quill.register(customAttribute);
Quill.register({
    'modules/better-table': QuillBetterTable
}, true);
this.quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    readOnly: this.editDisabled,
    modules: {
      toolbar: '#toolbar',
      table: false,
      'better-table': {},
      keyboard: {
        bindings: QuillBetterTable.keyboardBindings
      }
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});

Here I add the table and attribute to it:
let tableModule: any = this.quill.getModule('better-table');
tableModule.insertTable(2, 2);
let table = tableModule.getTable();
table[0].domNode.setAttribute('custom-attribute', 'test');

I expect Quill to read the attribute correctly, without cutting or moving it

I didn't understand why, but I solved it by writing this:
this.quill.root.innerHTML = html;

instead of:
const quillContent = this.quill.clipboard.convert({ html: html });
this.quill.setContents(quillContent, 'silent');

while reading the contents of quillenter code here
